# Geometric construction (problem from Swedish 12th grade ‘Student Exam’ from 1932)

Tags: geometric-construction

The following problem is taken from a Swedish 12th grade ‘Student Exam’ from 1932.

> Inscribe in a given circle a quadrangle in which de two diagonals have given lengths and, in addition, where the ratio between two adjacent sides are equal to a given ratio.

I have no clue on how to solve problems of this kind, possibly since the topic was dropped in the Swedish schools in the mid 1900s and will probably never be taken up again, and I find them very difficult. (Usually the solutions are very elegant and ‘easy’ once you see them but never easy to initially spot for the untrained eye.) The problem should be solved with only a pen, a straightedge and a compass. Problems of this kind were often the final question on the exams, and therefore the hardest one. All help and hints on how to solve this problem are much appreciated.

---

#### Initial ideas

Consider the image below where the given circle has been drawn. To the left are the given ratio $r$ and the given two diagonals.

We can place the first diagonal in the circle vertically as we can always rotate the problem around $O$.

We can (I think) remove the quadangle from the problem and rewrite it as: “Set the end points $P$ or $P'$ of the second diagonal so that they are $d_2$ apart and that the distances $PA$ and $P'A$ have the ratio $r$.” There is only need to set one of the end points of the second diagonal as the other end point is easy to draw when the first end point is placed.

The image below shows three such second-diagonal lines. For the 3rd I have drawn the adjacent sides in red. As $P_i$ “slides” on the circle (and $P_i'$ tags along) we ge a ratio from $0$ to $\infty$ (or $0$ to $1$, depending on how you look at the ratio). The question is how to place the second diagonal so it results in the specified ratio. Currently I have no idea.

[image]

---

#### The original problem

[image]

Comment: Which "two adjacent sides" should it be? Or could it be any 2 adjacent sides of our choosing?

Comment: I interpret the problem as “any two sides”. The Swedish text does not specify which sides, just “two adjacent sides”. There is always a risk that a test can contain typos, but these tests from that time period were often very well made without any typos, not like test in the latter decades in Swedish schools.

Answer (score 0):

Comment

Not clear in what manner the adjacent sides bear a ratio $p$. Assuming equal sides are placed at opposite positions as

$( a, ap,a, ap),$ then by Ptolemy theorem

$$ a^2(1+p^2) = d_1 d_2 $$

where $ (d_1,d_2) $ are the diagonals...

Using Ruler/Compass a rectangle  can be constructed as a special (trivial?) case inside a cyclic quadrilateral.

[image]

Comment: I updated the question with “Initial ideas” with an image that I think describes the problem.

Comment: Please vote for undelete https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954331/what-are-the-circles-preserved-by-an-inversion/3954335#3954335